# structure used in private using c++

Tags: object, structure, private

I am trying to run this code but it is throwing an error. Can't figure it how to resolve it. I am new to structure and I was trying to make a link list program.

The error:

```
 S_linklist1.cpp: In member function ‘linklist::NODE linklist::create_node(int)’: S_linklist1.cpp:23:11:
   error: could not convert ‘temp’ from ‘linklist::NODE*’ to ‘linklist::NODE’ return temp;
S_linklist1.cpp: In member function ‘void linklist::add(int)’: S_linklist1.cpp:35:7:
  error: cannot convert ‘linklist::NODE’ to ‘linklist::NODE*’ in assignment temp1=create_node(data);
```

The program:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstdlib>

using namespace std;

class linklist{
    private: struct NODE {
            int data;
            struct NODE* link;
        };
        struct NODE* START=NULL;

        NODE create_node(int s_data)
        {   
            struct NODE* temp;
            temp=new NODE;

            temp->data=s_data;
            temp->link=NULL;

            return temp;

        }

public : void add(int);
};

void linklist :: add(int data)
{
    struct NODE* temp1;
    temp1=new NODE;

    temp1=create_node(data);
    cout<<"Return success"<<"\n";
}

int main()
{
    linklist obj;
    obj.add(10);
}
```

Please help me with this.  Thanks

Comment: This is the error                                                                                                              S_linklist1.cpp: In member function ‘linklist::NODE linklist::create_node(int)’: S_linklist1.cpp:23:11: error: could not convert ‘temp’ from ‘linklist::NODE*’ to ‘linklist::NODE’ return temp; ^ S_linklist1.cpp: In member function ‘void linklist::add(int)’: S_linklist1.cpp:35:7: error: cannot convert ‘linklist::NODE’ to ‘linklist::NODE*’ in assignment temp1=create_node(data);

Comment: add error msg from comment

Answer (score 0):

Changing

```
NODE create_node(int s_data)
```

To

```
NODE *create_node(int s_data)
```

it is compiled on g++4.8.4.

BTW 'struct NODE' can be simply 'NODE' in C++.

Comment: S_linklist1.cpp: In member function ‘linklist::NODE linklist::create_node(int)’:
S_linklist1.cpp:23:11: error: could not convert ‘temp’ from ‘linklist::NODE*’ to ‘linklist::NODE’
    return temp;
           ^
S_linklist1.cpp: In member function ‘void linklist::add(int)’:
S_linklist1.cpp:35:7: error: cannot convert ‘linklist::NODE’ to ‘linklist::NODE*’ in assignment
  temp1=create_node(data);

Comment: Just put * in front of create_node to return a pointer instead of an instance.